# Word addin ooxml and style

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I try to create a word addin for my company. Basically, I want to add a specific paragraph to my text with specific style.

We have a document with all our styles and I want to use these styles for the string I add with my addin. But I don't find a way to use current document styles with OOXML, only create styles.

Currently, I use :

```
            <w:styles xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" >
            <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Heading1">
                <w:name w:val="heading 1"/>
                <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
                <w:next w:val="Normal"/>
                <w:link w:val="Heading1Char"/>
                <w:uiPriority w:val="9"/>
                <w:qFormat/>
                <w:pPr>
                    <w:keepNext/>
                    <w:keepLines/>
                    <w:spacing w:before="240" w:after="0" w:line="259" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                    <w:outlineLvl w:val="0"/>
                </w:pPr>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="majorEastAsia" w:hAnsiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:cstheme="majorBidi"/>
                    <w:color w:val="2E74B5" w:themeColor="accent1" w:themeShade="BF"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="32"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="32"/>
                </w:rPr>
            </w:style>
            <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:customStyle="1" w:styleId="Niveau4">
                <w:name w:val="Niveau 4"/>
                <w:basedOn w:val="Titre4"/>
                <w:next w:val="Normal"/>
                <w:uiPriority w:val="4"/>
                <w:qFormat/>
                <w:rsid w:val="006E5D5C"/>
                <w:pPr>
                    <w:numPr>
                        <w:ilvl w:val="3"/>
                        <w:numId w:val="3"/>
                    </w:numPr>
                    <w:contextualSpacing/>
                    <w:outlineLvl w:val="4"/>
                </w:pPr>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:b w:val="0"/>
                    <w:u w:val="single"/>
                </w:rPr>
            </w:style>
        </w:styles>
```

Is it possible to retrieve document's styles and use them in ooxml ? Or must I add styles each time ?

Thanks

Comment: Styles are accessible in the document, but it's within a part specific to styles.  If you are using the open source openxml objects, you'll need to look at MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart.  If you are dealing in the xml directly there should be a styles.xml within the docx package.   Not sure if referencing msword directly, I don't use that one.